# How do I disable 7-Zip directory scan for directories which are not meant to be compressed and added to the archive?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

7-Zip is an awesome tool, but sometimes it works in a strange way. Consider the following directory `D:\dir` layout:

```
foo   <DIR>
bar   <DIR>
baz   <DIR>
empty <DIR> -- this directory is empty by intention
```

Now when executing the following commands:

```
>D:
>cd D:\dir
>7z a -r -bb3 -mx9 -mmt -ms empty.7z empty
7-Zip [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04

Scanning the drive:
    0M Scan foo\bar\baz
```

For some reason 7-Zip scans directories that are not relevant to the compression process. This is relevant to 7-Zip [64] 16.04, but it worked like that in much older versions. Not sure if it's also reproducible on Linux.

How do I disable the scan and make 7-Zip analyze the specified directory recursively only?

---

#### Edit

Igor Pavlov, the creator of 7-Zip, has kindly clarified to me how `7z` works for such a scenario.

Comment: Could not reproduce on Windows.

Comment: Are your "non-relevant" directories big enough so that `7z` could take some time to scan them? What if you try to archive an empty directory, say `C:\7ztest`, from the root of your drive C?

Comment: Aha! Now I am seeing it. Maybe you should file a bug report.

Comment: @FleetCommand Interesting. I bet that 7z worked like that even for much older versions (if I'm not mistaken I used a 2010 version before 16.0.4), and it's hard to believe that Igor Pavlov is not aware of this behavior. I'll consider a bug report, thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was asking the [same question](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/3deeef66/) at the official 7-Zip forums, and got the reply from Igor Pavlov. I would like to get the answer from Igor at the site, but he seems not to have an account here. He suggests just to remove the `-r` switch, since `7z` uses recursive search by default:

> Your command searches empty file or folder in all subfolders.
>   Remove `-r` switch.
>
> http://7-zip.org/faq.html

Here is the respective excerpt from the official FAQ:

> **Why doesn't -r switch work as expected?**
>
> In most cases you don't need -r switch. 7-Zip can compress subfolders even without -r switch.
>
> Example 1:
>    `7z.exe a c:\a.7z "C:\Program Files"`
>   compresses "C:\Program Files" completely, including all subfolders.
>
> Example 2:
>    `7z.exe a -r c:\a.7z "C:\Program Files"`
>   searches and compresses "Program Files" in all subfolders of C:\ (for example, in "C:\WINDOWS").
>
> If you need to compress only files with some extension, you can use -r switch:
>    `7z a -r c:\a.zip c:\dir\*.txt`
>   compresses all *.txt files from folder c:\dir\ and all it's subfolders.

Comment: This is still pretty confusing. I hope someday Igor decides to remove/rename/fix the -r switch.